# Daily motivation screen theme for Android

Tags: android, health

I'm looking for a software or a dynamic theme that runs in the background and dynamically shows a new motivational quote every time I unlock the screen or go to the home screen in my Android phone (Realme Pro 2).

Is there anything that can do this?

An example of what I want is [this Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/daily-motivation-motivati/nonnkklkpbokmppgochfdamhihaijdin/related?hl=en)